# Kubernetes Python job fails: "flags cannot be placed before plugin name: --insecure-skip-tls-verify"

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have a local Minikube cluster and I am trying to submit jobs to it using the Python client. Here is the code:

```
from kubernetes import config, client


config.load_kube_config()

job_id = "test1"
image = "python:3.8.12"
command = ["echo"]


job = client.V1Job(api_version="batch/v1", kind="Job")
job.metadata = client.V1ObjectMeta(namespace="default", name=job_id)
job.status = client.V1JobStatus()

container = client.V1Container(name="default", image=image,
            env=[], command=command)

template = client.V1PodTemplate()
template.template = client.V1PodTemplateSpec()
template.template.spec = client.V1PodSpec(containers=[container], restart_policy = "Never")
template.template.spec.volumes = []

job.spec = client.V1JobSpec(template = template.template)


batch = client.BatchV1Api()
batch.create_namespaced_job(
        body = job,
        namespace='default'
)
```

The job is successfully submitted to Minikube, but it always fail. When I check the logs of the pod, I see the following error:

`Error: flags cannot be placed before plugin name: --insecure-skip-tls-verify`

I checked the config in `~/.kube/config`:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /lhome1/minikube/.minikube/ca.crt
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Wed, 26 Jan 2022 13:17:32 CET
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.22.0
      name: cluster_info
    server: https://192.168.49.2:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Wed, 26 Jan 2022 13:17:32 CET
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.22.0
      name: context_info
    namespace: default
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /lhome1/minikube/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /lhome1/minikube/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key
```

I have no idea of where this error is coming from.

Edit:
The result of `kubectl plugin list` is `error: unable to find any kubectl plugins in your PATH`. This is just a simple Minikube, I did not add anything to it.

Comment: Could you please check - by 
```kubectl plugin list``` command - which kubectl plugins are available on your local environment? Please also attach the entire log for the failed pod.

Comment: There are no plugins installed, as far as I know. This is the complete log of the pod, `kubectl logs <pod>` does not return anything else.

Comment: I used your script but I wasn't able to reproduce this issue on my minikube. It works as expected for me.
What machine are you running this script on?
What command are you using to run this script?
Could you please run the `kubectl version` command and share the output ?
Do you have the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable set ?
Is it possible for you to recreate the minikube cluster and try again ?